# preg_replace regex - skip output for lines that don't match the pattern

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a CSV file that I want to parse using PHP (don't want to use php csv functions since they're too slow for my case). I use preg_replace to select only the columns that I need and write output back to standard out. I have a pattern that look like that

```
preg_replace("/^\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\"(.*)$/m", "$1;$2", $content);
```

There are some lines in the CSV that are malformed. Is there a way to skip output for lines that don't match the pattern above?

Comment: You seriously believe that fgetcsv() or str_getcsv are slower than a homebrew regexp? I'd love to see some benchmark results

Comment: Yes, both fgetcsv and str_getcsv parse data into php array which is very slow. The solution using stream_get_content and str_getcsv needs 33s to parse 290MB CSV file compared to solution described below that needs aprox. 5s.

Comment: Interesting results, I'll have to run some tests of my own... I've a CSV application where that kind of speed improvement will be a real benefit for large files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

First remove all lines that don't match your regex:

```
preg_replace("/^(?!\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\".*$).*\r?\n/m", "", $content);
```

Then do the original regex replace.

However, you need to be *very* careful. As soon as you get linebreaks and/or escaped quotes in your CSV fields, these regexes may break and destroy your file.

Or imagine a malformed line like

```
"foo","bar (missing quote!)
"baz", "bam" (correct line)
```

The regex would now delete both the incomplete *and* the correct line because `[^\"]*` also eats the newlines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially warnings. My current idea is to assume that most of the csv files are well formed so I do regex replace and compare string length before and after replace. If they are the same everything is OK otherwise I do it line by line.